# Cannot fetch varbinary data from MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, sql-server-2014, php-7

**Background**

Development environment:

PHP 7.0.3 with Apache 2.4.16 on Windows 10 x64

SQL Server 2014 Standard

The sever has FileStream enabled on corresponding file columns.

Tried to install `sqlsvr` driver but failed due to lack of support to PHP7

Access SQL server from ODBC using driver `SQL Server`

**PHP Code to insert image data into MSSQL**

```
$link = @new \PDO("odbc:Driver={SQL Server};Server=$server;Database=$db", $user, $password);
$stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO [Attachment] (AttID, Seq , ModuleCde, AppID, StaffID , FileName , [File]) VALUES ( NEWID() , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? )");
$stmt->bindValue(1,$_POST["Seq"],PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(2,$_POST["ModuleCde"],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(3,$_POST["AppID"],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(4,$_SESSION["StaffID"],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(5,$_FILES["file"]["name"][$_POST["Seq"]],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(6,file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$_POST["Seq"]]),PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

**PHP Code to save image data from MSSQL**

```
$link = @new \PDO("odbc:Driver={SQL Server};Server=$server;Database=$db", $user, $password);
$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT DATALENGTH([File]) AS [Size] , CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),[File],2) AS [File] FROM [Attachment] WHERE [ModuleCde] = ? AND [AppID] = ? AND [Seq] = ? AND [StaffID] = ?");
$stmt->bindValue(1,$_GET["ModuleCde"],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(2,$_GET["AppID"],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(3,$_GET["Seq"],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(4,$_SESSION["StaffID"],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bindColumn(2,$img,PDO::PARAM_LOB, 0);
$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
file_put_contents( "file" , $img );
```

The file is successfully uploaded to the SQL sever. Opening the `DATA` directory of the SQL Server, all of the uploaded files and can be opened up by Paint.

But the file fetch from the above image saving code is corrupted. The file is missing some bytes from the original.

Method tried

```
fwrite( fopen("file","w+") , strtolower("0x".str_replace("\0","",$img)) );
```

and also the method stated in this link.

[Php with MSSQL display raw data from varbinary field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115578/php-with-mssql-display-raw-data-from-varbinary-field)

But both have no luck, the file also seemed to be corrupted.

Any help is appreciated.

**Edit 2016-02-25**

Modified the SQL statement as the following but the output file is still corrupted.

```
 $link->prepare("SELECT DATALENGTH([File]) AS [Size] , [File] FROM [Attachment] WHERE [ModuleCde] = ? AND [AppID] = ? AND [Seq] = ? AND [StaffID] = ?");
```

I am now trying to change different SQL server ODBC driver to see if the file can output successfully.

**Edit 2016-08-09**

With the updated MSSQL PDO Driver for PHP 7. Everything worked again with a charm.

Now, we don't need to `convert` the varbinary data anymore using this new driver.

[Reference Link](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When inserting into tables contain varbinary, choose of data type is very important to PHP PDO.

`PDO::PARAM_LOB` shall be used instead using `PDO::PARAM_STR` for file columns

To make sure DB has output the correct file through the driver, convert the `VARBINARY(MAX)` field into hex string and hand it over to PHP normally using this method `CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),[FileColumn],2)`

Converting the column to `VARCHAR(MAX)` rather than `NVARCHAR(MAX)` because HEX strings do not need any support to Unicode and leave a plain HEX string.

Then hex strings can be convert back from hex data to binary through PHP function `hex2bin()` efficiently.

**The Solution**

```
$link = @new \PDO("odbc:Driver={SQL Server};Server=$server;Database=$db", $user, $password);
$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT DATALENGTH([File]) AS [Size] , CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),[File],2) AS [File] FROM [Attachment] WHERE [ModuleCde] = ? AND [AppID] = ? AND [Seq] = ? AND [StaffID] = ?");
$stmt->bindValue(1,$_GET["ModuleCde"],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(2,$_GET["AppID"],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(3,$_GET["Seq"],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(4,$_SESSION["StaffID"],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
file_put_contents( "file" , hex2bin($result["File"]) );
```

**Additional Information**

When selecting varbinary column from `SQL Server Native Client 11.0` and `ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server`, neither converting the column to `varchar` or not, PHP outputs a corrupted binary result which is unwanted. But driver `SQL Server` successfully return a HEX string to me when I am converting the column to `VARCHAR(MAX)`. I suspect this action is a bug or a driver issue.

Comment: I'm gonna cry!! I've been struggling with php pdo's and varbinary data comming from mssql servers... Your answer helped a lot!! Can I send an e-hug? :D Now... Where can I learn more about this? What is the name of this "technique"? or something like that, so I can google more and get more knowledge

Comment: I am glad that this helps you. This is not a kind of technique, I just get to this solution by trial and error. Since I find out that there are some bug reports regarding php and ODBC drivers point out that these drivers aren't outputting valid Unicode data. I am afraid that `varbinary` data will also be processed as Unicode so I tried to convert it into hex string which will not be false interpreted by the driver. After trying that, I successfully return a valid hex string to PHP. Then I convert that bunch of string to file. That's the trick.

Comment: When we stuck at a type of data, try to process it / encode it to make it into plain text. This is the trick I've done.

Comment: Before finding out this method, I just convert the file with `base64_encode` and inserting into the database's `text` column and return it to file by using `base64_decode`:D

Answer (score 3):

If you're storing binary data don't convert it to NVARCHAR() when selecting it -- try removing the CONVERT() from this:

```
$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT DATALENGTH([File]) AS [Size] , CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),[File],2) AS [File] FROM [Attachment] WHERE [ModuleCde] = ? AND [AppID] = ? AND [Seq] = ? AND [StaffID] = ?");
```

be this:

```
$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT DATALENGTH([File]) AS [Size], [File] FROM [Attachment] WHERE [ModuleCde] = ? AND [AppID] = ? AND [Seq] = ? AND [StaffID] = ?");
```

You also want to make sure you column is `VARBINARY(MAX)`.

When inserting your data I think you need to use `SQLSRV_ENCODING_BINARY` (instead of `PDO::PARAM_STR`)

Comment: Thank you for you reply, as I cannot install `sqlsvr` PDO driver so I afraid I cannot use `SQLSRV_ENCODING_BINARY`

Comment: @MiKeNeko, Would `PDO::PARAM_LOB` be more useful? It gives clues to PDO and the database driver to handle the data differently rather than just as strings.

Comment: @Ryan Vincent Thank you for your clue, I found the problem is a SQL sever driver issue and the problem is now fixed.